# How to add one-off packages to the configuration declaratively?

Tags: nixos

After using `nix-build` to install a package from unstable, how do i add it to the configuration.nix?

```
nix-build -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz idea-ultimate
```

The only approach i could think of is using the build-in function `fetchTarball` on the archive to some temporary location and then nix-env -f on it - is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the channel as root

```
sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable unstable
sudo nix-channel --update unstable
```

and add the package to `configuration.nix` like this:

```
systemPackages = [ ... (import <unstable> {}).idea.idea-ultimate ];
```

If you just want to install it to your user profile, use `nix-env`. I would just add the channel instead of fiddling with `fetchTarball` though. (Then it's simply `nix-env -iA unstable.idea.idea-ultimate`.)

Not sure this is the most idiomatic way.

Comment: there seems to be no way to set an aliased channel from the config itself that is documented anywhere, but this surely is a nice trick, thanks!